# Multiple Stage Hurdle Model Analyses

Tags: stata, zero-inflation

I have a dilemma over the application of double hurdle model. 
Here is a description of the data that I want to analyze: 
 1. Binary info on household purchase of different milk products 
 2. If products is purchased above, I have the quantities purchased and
    prices 
 3. Of the quantities purchased, who consumed in the household
    and the quantities for each member (Intrahousehold allocation)

My objective is to analyze this data to produce empirical evidence on determinants of milk purchases and intrahousehold allocations - I have sociodemographic household information too

Previous studies have employed double hurdle to analyze participation and determinants of the purchase, but my worry is how to go beyond this stage to look at the intrahousehold allocations, with an interest of how sociodemographic factors influence children access to milk

I welcome suggestions on how to go about this as I am pretty green on this.